# extracting from two tables and getting total money paid by a student in a single term

Tags: mysql

i have two tables, fees and seet,seet looks like this

```
**class** **term**  **payable**

  1p         term1     20000
```

and fees looks like this

```
**regNo** **class** **term** **paid** **date**

5685        1p         term1    8000     2002-12-22

5685        1p         term1    9000     2002-12-24

1234        1p         term1    15000     2002-12-21

4321        1p         term1    4000     2002-12-22
```

the regNo is unique for every student, the student can pay as many times as p0ssible within a term, i want to obtain the total each student paid and subtract it from payable in the seet table within a single query
i tried it with the query below

```
select (seet.payable - fees.paid) as balance , fees.adm 
from fees, seet 
where fees.term = seet.term and fees.class = seet.class 
      and fees.class = '1p' and fees.term = 'term1'
```

which gives me

```
balance     adm

12000       5685

11000       5685

5000        1234

16000       4321
```

the answer should be

```
balance      adm
3000         5685

5000         1234

16000        4321
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an inner query to sum up paid amount by regNo, class, and term. Then, compute the balance.

```
select b.regNo, b.class, b.term, a.payable - b.total_paid balance
from seet a
join (
    select regNo, class, term, sum(paid) total_paid
    from fees
    group by regNo, class, term ) b on a.class = b.class and a.term = b.term;
```

Comment: no column regNo in seet...so it wont work
table seet contains only class,term and payable

Comment: @abdulazizibrahim, sorry got the tables confused. see updated answer